# Как тестировать строки? jUnit

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit, testng

Всем привет, столкнулся с данной проблемой: не могу нормально запустить тест на JUnit когда нужно проверить несколько строк. Когда проверяю однострочный текст - нормально, когда многострочный - ругается.

Класс: Part1

```
final static String dir = "part1.txt";

static String readText(){
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try(FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(dir)){
        int c;
        while ((c = fileReader.read())!=-1){
            text.append((char)c);
        }
    }catch (IOException ex){
        ex.getMessage();
    }
    return text.toString();
}
```

Класс: Part1Test

```
String string = "Some\ntext";

@Test
public void testReadText() {
    assertEquals(string, Part1.readText());
}
```

Файл: part1.txt

```
Some
text
```

Ошибка:

```
com.epam.rd.java.basic.practice3.Part1Test > testReadText FAILED
    org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<Some[]
    text> but was:<Some[
]
    text>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
        at com.epam.rd.java.basic.practice3.Part1Test.testReadText(Part1Test.java:12)
```

Comment: Для отладки печатайте значения `c` в цикле. Будет интересно. Голосую за перевод строки в конце последней строки в файле.

Comment: Иногда пренебрегаю отладкой, каюсь :d. На деле же оказалось, что есть лишний \r после переноса строки. Тобишь всегда перед \n последует \r.

Answer (score 1):

Оставлю ответ для потомков))
Оказалось, что при чтении из файла(насколько я понял) ставиться \r перед \n. Вот как это выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это означает две вещи: вы работаете на Windows и FileReader читает файлы посимвольно. Первое ещё туда-сюда, а второе не годится. В ["The Java I/O libraries do not transparently translate..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages) объясняется что Java не транслирует переводы строк, но предлагает другие средства.

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема в разделителе строк (а они бывают разные: `\r, \n, \r\n`), то используя JUnit и Assertj можно сравнивать строки без учёта этого разделителя.

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

...

assertThat(resultString).isEqualToIgnoringWhitespace(expectedString);
```